# How to trigger CSS-Filter animation on Click (or Scrolling)

Tags: css, animation, scroll, triggers, click

How can i trigger a **Fade out** of a **CSS-Filter** when left-clicking or scrolling?

The Filter should fade out (from Black/White to Colorful when clicking on a button)

Comment: Welcome. Could you share what your research has shown so far, or how far you have progressed...?

Comment: If you show us your code, we will be able to help you much better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can learn more about it
[.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)

Try This Example

```
<div id="clickme">
  Click here
</div>
<img id="book" src="book.png" alt="" width="100" height="123">
```

**Script**

```
 <script>$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
      $( "#book" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
    });</script>
```